# Why for_each cannot replace for loop in the code?

Tags: rust

My original code is:

```
const DNA: [char; 4] = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'];
...
let mut map: HashMap<char, usize> = HashMap::new();
/* initialize the hashmap */

for d in DNA.iter() {
    map.insert(*d, 0);
}
```

The code was compiled.  Then I want to replace the for loop with for_each:

```
DNA.iter().for_each(|d| map.insert(*d, 0));
```

Compiling error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                                 
  --> src/lib.rs:26:29                                                                        
   |                                                                                          
26 |     DNA.iter().for_each(|d| map.insert(*d, 0));                                          
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Option`         
   |                                                                                          
   = note: expected unit type `()`                                                            
                   found enum `Option<usize>`
```

It seems for_each and for is not totally equivalent?  Why doesn't for_each  just ignore the return value of `map.insert()`?

Comment: "Ignore the return value"? It can't just change the type of what you give it. It expects a function returning `()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't for_each just ignore the return value of map.insert() ?

Because the Rust syntax simply doesn't work that way.

1. Every function has a return type, omitting it doesn't mean "no return value". That is syntactic sugar for `-> ()`, i.e. a return type of "unit".
2. Both an explicit `return map.insert(*d, 0);` and the shorthand of `map.insert(*d, 0)` without a semicolon at the end of a block are return statements. They are explicitly "do a return here", not an optional "maybe return a value if it might make sense".

Therefore, you're currently trying to provide an `Option<V>` where the function signature demands a `()`, which is why you get the error you've shown.

So you'll have to adjust your closure to not return that value (or more specifically, to return the unit type `()`):

```rust
// the explicit version
DNA.iter().for_each(|d| {
  map.insert(*d, 0);
  ()
});
// the more idiomatic, shorter equivalent
DNA.iter().for_each(|d| { map.insert(*d, 0); });
```

Notice how the first version does return a value that matches the function signature. The second version is just syntactic sugar, where you can omit a return value of `()`.

Comment: Thanks for the very explanation. I notice there's ';' after map.insert(*d, 0) in my original code.  While in the for_each version, I omit the semi-colon.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers explain what the problem is, and what the solution is (making the return type `()`). However, none mention that there is a function in the standard library, in the prelude, that does exactly this: it's `drop`. Indeed, `drop: fn(T) -> ()` for any type `T`, and it doesn't do anything more (it's [definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem/mod.rs.html#987) is literally `fn drop<T>(_: T) {}`).

So, to solve your problem, you can do

```rust
DNS.iter().for_each(|d| drop(map.insert(*d, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn for_each<F>(self, f: F)where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(Self::Item)
```

The above is the function signature of `std::iter::for_each`. Notice that the constraint `F: FnMut(Self::Item)` means that it can only be called with a callback function that takes a `Self::Item` as its input and returns nothing. If you *must* use `for_each` for this task, one option is to append a semicolon `;` to make the closure return nothing, although this has pretty much the same amount of punctuation as the `for ... in` version.

```rust
DNA.iter().for_each(|d| {
    map.insert(*d, 0);
});
```

[`std::iter::for_each` on Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each)